# How to locate phone without using GPS (Only network)

Tags: android, networking, position, locate

I want create my own apk, which send to database current location of mobile phone. I have apk which get position from Network provider, but it works only if GPS is enabled (At least for me). There's my question: Can I get location my mobile phone when GPS is off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google geolocation service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

First you have to scan all WiFi networks around you and have to POST 
Json formatted data like :

> {   "considerIp": "false",   "wifiAccessPoints": [
>       {
>           "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ac",
>           "signalStrength": -43,
>           "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
>       },
>       {
>           "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ad",
>           "signalStrength": -55,
>           "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
>       }   ] }

to URL

https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_KEY

as response you will receive location as Json data:

> {   "location": {
>       "lat": 33.3632256,
>       "lng": -117.0874871   },   "accuracy": 20 }